# How to stop Mvc and MvC web api function from Executing twice in slow internet connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have same function in both web api and Mvc Asp.Net project that send message . In web api I use ajax call to make request which is fine on good internet connection but when the internet is slow the function will send the message twice, sometimes three times. I have also try the same with normal Mvc project and still get the same result. I don't know why my function can't send the message once. I have been trying to sort this out now for three days but don't know why it keeping sending multiple times. Any help will be so much appreciated. below is function for webapi.

```
[Route("Vend")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Vend()
    {
        PayVendorModel model = new PayVendorModel();
        var rsp = new object();
        List<string> error = new List<string>();
        if (Request.Content.IsFormData())
        {
            var provider = Request.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync();
            model = (PayVendorModel)(ModelBinders.BindModel(provider.Result, new PayVendorModel()));

            UserProfile userProfile = Permissions.CurrentUser();
            bool isVtuSuccess = false;
            string vtuReference = string.Empty;

            AirVendResponse vend = RequestManager.GetAirVendForUser(Convert.ToInt32(model.Network), model.PhoneNumber, model.Amount, userProfile.VtUUsername, userProfile.PinCode).Result;


            if (vend.VendResponse.ResponseCode == "0")
            {
                isVtuSuccess = true;
                vtuReference = model.PhoneNumber;

                CashActivity cashAct = new CashActivity()
                {
                    IsVtuSuccess = isVtuSuccess,
                    Network = StringUtil.CheckNetwork(Convert.ToInt32(model.Network)),
                    PhoneNumber = vend.VendResponse.Msisdn,
                    RecordState = new RecordState(new Guid(userProfile.Id)),
                    Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(vend.VendResponse.Amount),
                    AVRef = vend.VendResponse.AVRef,
                    SellRef = vend.VendResponse.Ref

                };

                CashProvider.Add(cashAct);


                rsp = new
                {
                    message = "Succeeded",

                };
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, rsp);
            }
            else
            {
                rsp = new
             {
                 message = "Error Code: " + vend.VendResponse.ResponseCode + "\n Message: " + vend.VendResponse.ResponseMessage,

             };
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, rsp);

            }
        }
        else
        {

            error.Add("Error Creating Store.");
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelHelper.GetStringError(error));

        }
    }
```

Ajax

```
 $("#VendSaveBtn").unbind().bind("click", "#VendSaveBtn", function (e) {

    (e.preventDefault) ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
    if (!ValidateVend())
        CreateVend();


});

function CreateVend() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        timeout: GetTimeOut(),
        url: storeUrl + 'Vendor/Vend',
        data: $("#UserVendForm").serialize(),
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', GetTokenHeader());
        },
        success: function (result) {
            if(result.message =="Succeeded")
                changepage('#nav-panel');
            else
                createPopup(result.message)

        },
        error: function (req, s, t) {
            hideLoading();
            if (req.status == 401) {
                RemoveAccess();
                changepage("#LoginPage");
            }
            if (s === "timeout") {
                createPopup("Alert:", "Oops! check your internet connection.")
            } else if (req.status == 0) {
                createPopup("Alert:", internetMessage)
            } else if (req.status == 408) {
                createPopup("Alert:", internetServerError);
            } else {
                var messageArray = req.responseText;
                if (messageArray != undefined || messageArray != "") {
                    var newArray = JSON.parse(messageArray);
                    if (newArray.length > 1) {
                        for (var i = 1; i < newArray.length; i++) {
                            createPopup("Alert:", newArray[i].message);
                        }
                    } else {
                        $.each(newArray, function () {

                            createPopup("Alert:", this.message);
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    createPopup("Alert", "Oops something went wrong please try again.")
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

From normal MVC

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("PayCash","User", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="card-holder-name">Phone Number</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    @*<input type="text" style="height:50px" class="form-control" name="card-holder-name" id="card-holder-name" placeholder="Phone Number">*@
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "height:50px", @placeholder = "Phone Number", type = "number" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, null, validationStyle)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="card-holder-name">Amount</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    @*<input type="number" style="height:50px" class="form-control" name="card-holder-name" id="card-holder-name" placeholder="Amount">*@
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "height:50px", @placeholder = "Amount", type = "number" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Amount, null, validationStyle)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="expiry-month">Network</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Natwork, new SelectList(Model.Networks, "Value", "Text"), "Select", new { @class = "form-control col-sm-2", @style = "height:50px" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Natwork, null, validationStyle)
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="expiry-month"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-offset-9">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div>
                            <input type="submit" style="height:50px;width:200px" value="Send" class="btn btn-success">
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

MVC function

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> PayCash(PayVtuModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            UserProfile userProfile = Permissions.CurrentUser();
            bool isVtuSuccess = false;
            string vtuReference = string.Empty;

            AirVendResponse vend= await RequestManager.GetAirVendForUser(Convert.ToInt32(model.Natwork), model.PhoneNumber, model.Amount, userProfile.VtUUsername, userProfile.PinCode);

            if (vend.VendResponse.ResponseCode == "0")
            {
                isVtuSuccess = true;
                vtuReference = model.PhoneNumber;

                CashActivity cashAct = new CashActivity()
                {
                    IsVtuSuccess = isVtuSuccess,
                    Network = StringUtil.CheckNetwork(Convert.ToInt32(model.Natwork)),
                    PhoneNumber = vend.VendResponse.Msisdn,
                    RecordState = new RecordState(new Guid(userProfile.Id)),
                    Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(vend.VendResponse.Amount),
                    AVRef = vend.VendResponse.AVRef,
                    SellRef = vend.VendResponse.Ref

                };

                CashProvider.Add(cashAct);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
            }
            else
            {

                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error Code: " + vend.VendResponse.ResponseCode + "\n Message: " + vend.VendResponse.ResponseMessage);
            }
        }
        return View(model);

    }
```

Comment: You say you're using `ajax` to call the function. It would help if you shared from where you're calling it.

Comment: How many times are you calling this function from the client side. Monitor how many post requests are sent, since in the code that you shared is OK and cant cause this issue

Comment: Whatcha talkin bout Willis?  Where's your ajax?

Comment: If you're calling it from a `form` submit, are you sure you're not clicking the submit button more than once? Best practice is to disable the submit button after it's clicked.

Comment: Are you sure the ajax call was made only once ?

Comment: Show us the calling code and view

Comment: i have added  ajax and mvc call

Comment: @Brett. I have ajax loading on the form that frezz the screen on ajaxstart, So i am not clicking it twice.

Comment: Anybody have any suggestion

Comment: @JED Do what Alex suggested. You need to monitor how many post requests are sent and place breakpoints in your code and do a function call trace to find out why it keeps resending the request.

Comment: @Brett, During debugging i only get one request. The problem only occur on the server when i have low internet connection.

Comment: Ok, I'm confused, which function on the server is executing more than once, `Vend()` or `PayCash()`? Neither seem related to one another.

Comment: @Brett, the vend() is used in the Webapi controller while PayCash() is used on normal Mvc web controller and and getting 302 status code when ever it happens in fiddler for Paycash().

Comment: @JED Why is your MVC function written as an asynchronous task? I don't see why it's necessary. I think you've done something wrong with the implementation. Otherwise, you wouldn't be getting HTTP 302.

Comment: @Brett, because of await in this line.  AirVendResponse vend= await RequestManager.GetAirVendForUser(Convert.ToInt32(model.Natwork), model.PhoneNumber, model.Amount, userProfile.VtUUsername, userProfile.PinCode); is making api call to another server.